# How to find last to preview work and store to my field in xslt?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

HI How to find last to preview word in xslt i have search to google but not found correct solution can u please help me

MY code is

i have this code as like this

```
<tag>news/economy/policy/raghuram-rajan-sheds-dogmatism-in-policy-meet-makes-next-rbi-governors-job-easier</tag>
```

I want to search to last this word  "`/`" and

I want to result is `policy`

How to do this in xslt .

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? If not, which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using?

Comment: I used to 1.0 xslt

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor? If you don't know, see here how to find out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in pure XSLT 1.0, with no extensions, use:

```
<xsl:template name="token-before-last">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'/'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="next-text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($next-text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="token-before-last">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$next-text"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Example of call:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="token-before-last">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAB

---

If your processor supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function, you can do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(., '/')[last() -1]"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAB/1